# SQL Server : we want to get records from two tables on same fields different fields amount?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have three tables A, B, C. A table having masters information, B Table having billing information and C table having amount received information.

Now when I make a bill, data is inserted into B table, and when the payment is received, data is inserted into C table. So now if customer only makes half the payment, then payment entry goes into C table, but when I select customer it shows twice in the list with last time entered details.

Query:

```
select 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), p.PurDate, 103) PurDate,
    p.PurchaseNo, s.ClientID, s.SrNo, s.Ledger,
    p.Total, p.InvoiceTotal as PurchaseAmount,
    ISNULL(purecord.paidamt, 0) as paidamt,
    (p.InvoiceTotal - paidamt) as BalanceAmount,
    p.CompanyID, p.branchid1, p.finyearid
from 
    A as s
inner join 
    B as p on s.SrNo = p.SuppLedID
left join 
    (select 
         SUM(Purlamt) as paidamt, lid_rowid, Purno
     from 
         C
     group by 
         lid_rowid, Purno) as purecord on purecord.Purno = p.PurchaseNo
where 
    not exists (select *
                from C
                where p.InvoiceTotal = paidamt)
```

Result

```
PurDate PurchaseNo ClientID SrNo      Ledger       Total PurchaseAmount paidamt BalanceAmount
23/08/2017      43  2   SUP00002    OM COMPUTERS    4055    4055    4000    55
23/08/2017      43  2   SUP00002    OM COMPUTERS    4055    4055    165    3890
```

But we are expecting it should in second entry like below

```
PurDate PurchaseNo ClientID SrNo      Ledger       Total PurchaseAmount paidamt BalanceAmount
23/08/2017      43  2   SUP00002    OM COMPUTERS    4055    4055    4055    0
```

Comment: If you remove `lid_rowid` from the derived table `select` and `group by`, do you get your desired results?

Comment: Do you want the expected query to generate one row per Billing (B table) row, or something else?

Comment: As I see in the results, that customer paid 2 times: 4000+165=4165... And how do you get BalanceAmount = 0 in the expected result? What's the logic for that?

Comment: @SqlZim Thank you so much........ this resolved my issue........